# How to use order by with distinct in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables clients & exchange. I want to get clients id by running left join query. But when I run the query it throws an error.

```
select distinct
    `clients`.`id` as `client_id`
from `clients`
left join `exchange`
    on `clients`.`id` = `exchange`.`client_id`
where
    `clients`.`iex_status` = 'Active'
order by
    `exchange`.`validity_to` desc
```

error: [image]

Comment: The query you got an error on has `()` around `\`clients\`.\`id\` as \`client_id\`` which is what caused the error.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, and possibly the query in your question is not even what you actually ran to generate this error.  Note: You _don't_ need those ugly backticks, so you may remove them.

Comment: is there any other way to ?

Comment: what is your output after removing ()? is it still causing error?

Comment: I am not using ()

Comment: select distinct `clients.id` as `client_id` from `clients` left join `exchange` on `clients`.`id` = `exchange`.`client_id` where `clients`.`iex_status` = 'Active' order by `exchange`.`validity_to` desc

Comment: select distinct clients.id as c_id from clients left join exchange on clients.id = exchange.client_id where clients.iex_status = 'Active' order by exchange.validity_to desc Try this

Comment: Don't you first have to select a column before you can order by it?  I don't see exchange.validity_to in your select.

Comment: #3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'crm.exchange.validity_to' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Comment: How do you expect (c1, c2) data (1,3), (2,2), (1,1), `select distinct c1 ... order by c2` to be ordered?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. PS When you googled for 'site:stackoverflow.com' & your message without your specific strings & expression #, what did you learn?

Answer (score 1):

add `exchange`.`validity_to` this column into selection otherwise  it will throw this error `validity_to` is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

```
select distinct
    clients.id as client_id,exchange.validity_to
from clients
left join exchange
    on clients.id = exchange.client_id
where
    clients.iex_status = Active
order by
    exchange.validity_to desc
```

But from your screen shot it seems you used parenthesis after `distinct` thats why you got the error

Comment: @Strawberry, when SELECT DISTINCT only result-set columns may be used in the ORDER BY. However, this answer doesn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: @Strawberry https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be39f3ec75a51b730f91d0b70f0e4eb9 can you please check this link about distinct and order by

Comment: The asker does not want to select that column si this is no solution. See the duplicate link on the question for what the asker needs.

Comment: @jarlh Ah, I stand corrected. This is a new feature of MySQL 8, not present in MySQL 5.x (showing how out of date I am), and not present in MariaDB either. Anyway, I doubt that it's relevant to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you doing well, i have checked your query but found 2 diff. points 
1 : "select distinct `clients`.`id` as `client_id` from `clients` left join `exchange` on `clients`.`id` = `exchange`.`client_id` where `clients`.`iex_status` = 'Active' order by `exchange`.`validity_to` desc "

### You show this query in first and showing error in your query

2 : you are using "("  in your query that you have executed in sql i think your first query is right that will give you right result.

so please do not use ( ) in distinct fields.

thanks

Comment: Then how can I get unique result?

Comment: I am using this query:  select distinct clients.id as c_id from clients left join exchange on clients.id = exchange.client_id where clients.iex_status = 'Active' order by exchange.validity_to desc

Comment: @AJ Clarify via edits, not comments. Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As per your image attached you can modify alias out of braces as -

```
select distinct
    (`clients`.`id` as `client_id`) as 'client_id'
from `clients`
left join `exchange`
    on `clients`.`id` = `exchange`.`client_id`
where
    `clients`.`iex_status` = 'Active'
order by
    `exchange`.`validity_to` desc
```